# AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'add' - Operator Module

Tags: python, operator-keyword

I have a dictionary, and I am using the operator module to do so. This is what it looks like:

```
           ops =  {"+": operator.add,
                   "-": operator.sub,
                   "*": operator.mul,
                   "/": operator.div}
```

However, when I run the program I get the error:

`AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'add'`

How can I fix this?

Comment: Post your **actual code**. You're calling `operator.add()` without any arguments, but that won't raise the error you've posted in the question.

Comment: Also, please read this: [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary I added () as a mistake, I updated accordingly

Comment: you might have a local variable called `operator` overriding the import.

Comment: @karthikr, I see that I do have a local variable `operator` that is overriding the import

Comment: @karthikr you beat me to it. Yes, the problem is you have a variable named operator that is assigned a unicode string. I suspect you're probably wanting the user to input an operator.

Comment: @karthikr Yes, and I updated the code accordingly

Answer (score 0):

I had a local variable called operator that was overriding the import of the module.